# Create a function in Python that does SQLite queries and inserts

Tags: python, sqlite, function, insert, execute

This function I'm trying to write is not working, can someone help me figure out why?

I've looked at the example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966104/python-wrapper-preventing-function-call), but it is a little too different from what I have.

Something is wrong with the strings, I'm not sure how to properly place the SQLite queries in the string, the database I'm creating is not being populated.

Here is the what the function looks like so far:

```
def checkInsert(db_c, column, table, item, db_db):
    strng1 = ("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s=?", (item,)) % (column, table, column)
    strng2 = ("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(?);", (item,)) % (table, column)
    db_c.execute(strng1) 
    check = db_c.fetchone()
    if check is None:
        db_c.execute(strng2)
        db_db.commit()
    else:
        pass
```

Currently I have to write out all of the following script:

```
dog = "mastiff"
cat = "jaguar"
bird = "parrot"

mem_c.execute("SELECT dog FROM dogs WHERE dog=? ", (dog,))
dog_check = mem_c.fetchone()
if dog_check is None:
    mem_c.execute("INSERT INTO dogs (dog) VALUES(?);", (dog,))
    mem_db.commit()
else:
    pass
mem_c.execute("SELECT cat FROM cats WHERE cat=? ", (cat,))
cat_check = mem_c.fetchone()
if cat_check is None:
    mem_c.execute("INSERT INTO cats (cat) VALUES(?);", (cat,))
    mem_db.commit()
else:
    pass
mem_c.execute("SELECT bird FROM birds WHERE bird=? ", (bird,))
bird_check = mem_c.fetchone()
if bird_check is None:
    mem_c.execute("INSERT INTO birds (bird) VALUES(?);", (bird,))
    mem_db.commit()
else:
    pass
```

If I get this right, the function should allow me to take above script and instead write it out simply, like this:

```
dog = "mastiff"
cat = "jaguar"
bird = "parrot"

checkInsert(mem_c, 'dog', 'dogs', dog, mem_db)
checkInsert(mem_c, 'cat', 'cats', cat, mem_db)
checkInsert(mem_c, 'bird', 'birds', bird, mem_db)
```

Comment: Have you considered using Django and its powerful ORM. IRL you might have hard times trying to implement everything on your own instead of using of framework, especially so good as Django is.

Comment: What is your question? So far you just told us what you want to do...  Nevertheless: one obvious error is that `'column, table, column'` should actually be `(column, table, column)` in the `strng1` definition. The same error exists in the `strng2` line.

Comment: sorry, trying to write a function, it is currently not working, trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!  Originally I was not formatting the string correctly.

The problem was that I was trying to somehow place the `item` variable in the string, when it is supposed to be in the `db_c.execute` line so that the query can be properly executed.

Basically the query strings need to first be defined using the column and table strings, then once the query needs to be executed, the query string and `item` variable is placed in the `db_c.execute()` function.

Hopefully this helps if anyone else is having this problem.

```
def checkInsert(db_c, column, table, item, db_db):
    strng1 = "SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s=?" % (column, table, column)
    strng2 = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(?);" % (table, column)
    db_c.execute(strng1, (item,))
    check = db_c.fetchone()
    if check is None:
        db_c.execute(strng2, (item,))
        db_db.commit()
    else:
        pass
```